# jquery jqgrid paging: display the wrong total pages number

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, jqgrid

My Json data from wcf:

{"page:1","total:5","records:15"}

But the result data shown as:
page 1 of 0  (wrong total page number)
view 1-5 of 5 (wrong records)

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you copy and paste in your actual JSON instead of typing it, because that's something that wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 3):

The data

```json
{"page:1","total:5","records:15"}
```

are wrong. It should be at least as

```json
{"page":1,"total":5,"records":15}
```

of better as

```json
{"page":1,"total":5,"records":15,"rows":[]}
```